# How can I launch the Alarms App through a Universal Windows App

Tags: win-universal-app

I am trying to launch the default Alarms App somewhere in my app through an action the user performs. I know you can now add your own alarms and notifications but I want the user to be able to use the default Alarms App.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Launcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh701476) class to launch the Alarms App by uri as follows:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-clock:"));
```

The uri of Alarms&CLock is `ms-clock` in system. You can find the protocol in Settings->System->Default Apps->Choose default app by protocol in a PC device. Pay attention the Alarm&Clock app should be existed in the device. More details you can reference:[Launch the default app for a URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app)

Comment: Interesting workaround. I think this might just do it. Workaround in that if I wanted to change the Alarms App to something else later I would be out of luck if there weren't a standard protocol for that.

Comment: I would downvote my answer if I could :) Great find @Sunteen

Comment: @AlexDrenea Too bad you deleted your answer. I learned out of it that there is no way to launch another app, except if you build in it some protocol or if the app you want to call already has a default protocol bound to it. Whoever stumbled upon this page would have learned that (in addition to the very specific answer to my question).

Comment: fair enough. I will undelete and change it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

With the Universal Application Model it is not possible to launch other apps at random. You can only launch an app if it enables deep-linking.

[Here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/22/using-cross-app-communication-to-make-apps-work-together-10-by-10/) is a great article about deep-linking and app to app communication in general.

For your particular question, @Sunteen provided a great answer as to how to open the `alarms` app but more importantly, how you can find which apps you can open and what their protocol extension is.

Comment: I was afraid this might be the case.