# Unable to launch Windows App with Process in Windows 10 Anniversary Update

Tags: c#, process, windows-10, launch

I'm trying to make a simple launcher for Windows Apps. Specifically for the Mail App

```
public static void Main()
{
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"shell:Appsfolder\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.windowslive.mail";
        proc.Start();

        // Short code
        //Process.Start("explorer", @"shell:Appsfolder\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.windowslive.mail");
}
```

This code is not working for me after i installed the Anniversary Update.
It was working with the previous version of Windows.
Can someone test it?
Do I need to add something?

If I run this command through Run it's working though.

Comment: assuming the Mail app is your default mail handler you could just run `mailto://`  (setting proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute to True) to open the default mail app.

Comment: That's not the result I want. I just want to open the Mail app. If I use your suggestion (mailto://) the result is it tries to create new email. Moreover I have more that one account there and when the app starts it asks me to choose the account from which the email will be sent.

Comment: https://powertoe.wordpress.com/2012/11/02/get-a-list-of-metro-apps-and-launch-them-in-windows-8-using-powershell/

Comment: Thank you but that applies only to Win8. Start-MetroApp command is not recognized under Win10.

Comment: You can't be helped if you refuse to read.  Skimming won't do you any good here.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested it in my side, it actually not open the email but just open my document folder.
But I don't think you need to use such a complex code to launch the Mail app.
Just using the following code(Launch the mail by Uri `ms-unistore-email`):

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "ms-unistore-email://";   
proc.Start();
```

Using a Uri to launch a app is popular in code. The following link you can reference: [How can I launch the Alarms App through a Universal Windows App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37953829/how-can-i-launch-the-alarms-app-through-a-universal-windows-app/37962056#37962056)

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to validate that there is a change in Windows 10 anniversary that makes launching Windows App more tricky. I have experienced the same issue as you had (I am using java instead of C#). **I have replaced** :

> "explorer shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsCamera_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App"

**by**

> "explorer microsoft.windows.camera:"

to make it work (in this case the camera).
Note that both commands works when they are directly executed from windows but only the second one works when launched from a third party program.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Unfortulately I'm back to 1151. I'll try Anniversary update later when it gets better. i had one more problem. I had a Windows forms app that doesn't work On Anniversary Update. Is it just me or there is something else changed?